# Qual é a diferença entre integração contínua e entrega contínua?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, integração-contínua

São dois termos muito utilizados, e muitas vezes até como sinônimos. Mas qual é a diferença entre eles (se há alguma)? Quais as ferramentas mais comuns utilizadas nos dois cenários?

Comment: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/08/05/continuous-integration-delivery-and-deployment-with-gitlab/

Answer (score 15):

## Integração é processo. Entrega é resultado.

A integração contínua é um processo com o propósito de controlar o ciclo de vida do código de um sistema desenvolvido por várias pessoas e que têm vários módulos distintos que precisam ser "integrados". Além de serem integrados esse processo tenta garantir que isso ocorra continuamente, ou seja, que exista um certo padrão nos procedimentos que permita tratar os problemas que ocorrerem de uma forma lógica sem ter que parar para pensar na solução a cada problema.

Os partes mais comuns da integração contínua (bem resumidamente) são:

- **Repositórios de código fonte**: em que você pode controlar as versões, ou seja, é possível ter uma "foto" do código fonte de cada pacote que você quer liberar para testes, por exemplo. O mais comum é um repositório Git.
- **Etapas de Build**: em que você pode ter um *script* automatizado que faz a compilação do código fonte e gera um "pacote" testável do seu sistema. No caso em que o código não compila, os desenvolvedores são alertados assim que fazem o *commit* dos fontes.
- **Etapas de Testes**: em que você pode realizar testes manuais ou automatizados (unitários, integração, etc) dos seus pacotes.
- **Setup**: em que você pode gerar um "pacote" de todo o sistema e que pode ser instalado em um ambiente para testes ou para produção.
- **Implantação**: em que pode haver um *script* para instalar o "pacote" automaticamente no ambiente de produção.

A entrega contínua é um resultado do processo de integração continua com entrega de pacotes instaláveis para o cliente, ou seja, a cada período é feito a entrega de um pacote do sistema que contém os ajustes e novas funções.

Dessa forma, é possível ter o processo de integração contínua sem necessariamente fazer entregas contínuas. O termo "Integração Contínua" vem da década de 1990 e "Entrega Contínua" é mais recente porque se tornou mais viável com as novas tecnologias e softwares dedicados a rodar e monitorar os processos.

---

Recentemente (pra mim) apareceu outro termo nesse processo chamado **Implantação Contínua**. Basicamente, para não entrar em detalhes, a implantação seria uma passo além da entrega. A entrega termina com sistema pronto para ser implantado em algum cliente ou em um ambiente de produção, já a implantação contínua seria o processo em que essa parte também estaria automatizada.

*Atualizei as etapas na lista acima com essa nova fase do processo.*

Comment: Curti o conceito de implantação contínua. Gostaria de ler mais a respeito. Se achar que não é do escopo desta resposta, você poderia fazer uma pergunta auto-respondida e linkar aqui (ou comentar abaixo). Eu ficaria agradecido. A propósito, não sei como abordar uma pergunta no assunto, por isso eu mesmo não a faço

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu peguei esse conceito num [episódio de podcast](https://hipsters.tech/primeiros-passos-com-devops-hipsters-81/). Se quiser ler mais acho que pode começar pelo livro do Danilo que participou do episódio. Na página do podcast tem o link para o livro dele.

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta, excelente!

Answer (score 11):

Pesquisando na Internet:

- https://www.4linux.com.br/diferencas-entre-integracao-deploy-e-entrega-continua

**A Integração contínua** promove o trabalho conjunto e para isso é essencial que o uso de uma solução de controle de versão, como o Gitlab, Github, CVS ou Subversion. Essas ferramentas criam um repositório principal para armazenar o código e manter versões com cada modificação realizada para que seja possível revertê-las e auditá-las sempre que preciso.

**A Entrega Contínua** é um conjunto de práticas com o objetivo de garantir que um novo código esteja apto para ser disponibilizado em ambiente de produção. A prática incorpora além de todas ações previstas na Integração Contínua, processos adicionais e necessários para que a modificação seja acessível a usuários e assim sejam realizadas inspeções finais, sejam elas manuais e/ou automatizadas.

Comment: o que você escreveu sobre integração continua, seria somente controle de versão, ou seja, parte de um processo muito maior.

Answer (score 7):

Aproveitando as definições da Amazon:

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/devops/continuous-delivery/

> A entrega contínua é uma prática de desenvolvimento de software de DevOps em que alterações de código são criadas, testadas e preparadas automaticamente para liberação para produção. Ela expande com base na integração contínua ao implantar todas alterações de código em um ambiente de teste e/ou ambiente de produção, após o estágio de criação. Quando a integração contínua for implementada adequadamente, os desenvolvedores sempre terão um artefato de criação pronto para ser implantado, e que passou por um processo de teste padronizado.

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/devops/continuous-integration/

> A integração contínua é uma prática de desenvolvimento de software de DevOps em que os desenvolvedores, com frequência, juntam suas alterações de código em um repositório central. Depois disso, criações e testes são executados. Geralmente, a integração contínua se refere ao estágio de criação ou integração do processo de lançamento de software, além de originar um componente de automação (ex.: uma CI ou serviço de criação) e um componente cultural (ex.: aprender a integrar com frequência). Os principais objetivos da integração contínua são encontrar e investigar bugs mais rapidamente, melhorar a qualidade do software e reduzir o tempo que leva para validar e lançar novas atualizações de software.

Answer (score 3):

devmedia também fala do assunto:

- [INTEGRAÇÃO](http://www.devmedia.com.br/integracao-continua-uma-introducao-ao-assunto/28002)

> A integração contínua é um termo originado na metodologia ágil XP e
>    utilizado em diversas metodologias, consistindo em algo simples: o
>    desenvolvedor integra o código alterado e/ou desenvolvido ao projeto
>    principal na mesma frequência com que as funcionalidades são
>    desenvolvidas, sendo feito muitas vezes ao dia ao invés de apenas uma
>    vez. O objetivo principal de utilizar a integração contínua é
>    verificar se as alterações ou novas funcionalidades não criaram novos
>    defeitos no projeto já existente. A prática da integração contínua
>    pode ser feita através de processos manuais ou automatizados,
>    utilizando ferramentas como o Jenkins, Hudson entre outros.

- [ENTREGA](http://www.devmedia.com.br/entrega-continua-de-software-revista-net-magazine-100/26312)

> A entrega contínua existe para que as funcionalidades sejam liberadas
>    continuamente e de forma segura para o cliente. Imagine que ao
>    submeter um arquivo para o repositório de código-fonte, o ambiente de
>    homologação seja automaticamente atualizado e o ajuste seja
>    disponibilizado para testes sem a necessidade de intervenção manual.