# O que é Travis CI?

Tags: testes, travis-ci, integração-contínua

Eu estou fazendo uma pesquisa sobre teste de software (ambientes de teste integrado, depuração e manutenção) e encontrei esse Travis CI, mas meu inglês não é muito bom e não achei artigos em português. Basicamente, o que é e pra que serve Travis CI? E como eu posso fazer uso dele?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O *CI* significa *Continuous integration* (integração continua), ou seja, se refere a uma série de testes que você pode escrever para garantir que os seus códigos e afins funcionem da maneira esperada através de testes unitários.

Alguns links úteis:

- [Qual é a diferença entre integração contínua e entrega contínua?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182382/3635)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

O Travis-CI é uma ferramenta que você integra com o teu repositório online (no caso creio que apenas o Github) para que toda vez que você subir uma atualização o próprio Travis-CI irá fazer os testes nos ambientes que você desejar/configurar.

Supondo que eu escrevi um script para PHP e configurei o phpunit (teste unitário para PHP), então eu defini o `.travis.yml` que deve estar no mesmo repositório assim:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.6
  - 7.0
  - 7.1
```

Claro também deve-se colocar no repositório os testes que escreveu (dependendo da tecnologia que usa)

O Travis-CI suporta muitas linguagens ou tecnologias e com isto diferentes tipos de testes (que claro é você que escreve):

- [Android](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/)
- [C](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/c/)
- [C#](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/csharp/)
- [C++](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/cpp/)
- [Clojure](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/clojure/)
- [Crystal](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/crystal/)
- [D](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/d/)
- [Dart](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/dart/)
- [Elixir](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/elixir/)
- [Elm](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/elm/)
- [Erlang](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/erlang/)
- [F#](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/csharp/)
- [Generic](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/minimal-and-generic/)
- [Go](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/)
- [Groovy](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/groovy/)
- [Haskell](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/haskell/)
- [Haxe](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/haxe/)
- [Java](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/)
- [JavaScript <sup>(with Node.js)</sup>](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/)
- [Julia](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/julia/)
- [MATLAB](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/matlab/)
- [Minimal](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/minimal-and-generic/)
- [Nix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/nix/)
- [Objective-C](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/)
- [Perl](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/perl/)
- [Perl6](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/perl6/)
- [PHP](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/)
- [Python](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/)
- [R](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/)
- [Ruby](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/)
- [Rust](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/rust/)
- [Scala](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/scala/)
- [Smalltalk](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/smalltalk/)
- [Swift](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/)
- [Visual Basic](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/csharp/)

> **Nota:** Desde [15 de Junho de 2021](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2021-05-07-orgshutdown) o `travis-ci.org` foi encerrado, agora todos processos foram unificados no domínio `travis-ci.com` e os preços dos serviço podem ser consultados em https://www.travis-ci.com/pricing/, tendo a possibilidade de fazer testes por 30 dias (o que ainda obriga o uso de cartão de crédito).

Answer (score 9):

É uma ferramenta de integração contínua. Esta é uma metodologia que prega que tudo o que vai sendo feito do desenvolvimento deve ser integrado imediatamente, em geral várias vezes ao dia. Então você tem o projeto centralizado onde todos os desenvolvedores vão colocando suas modificações onde o sistema é testado e construído de forma completa mostrando se algo está dando errado e identificando problemas logo que eles aparecem e não mais tarde quando pode ser mais complicado.

Quando falo em testes falo de um conjunto de verificações de qualidade e não apenas testes de unidade.

Em alguns casos a própria implantação acaba sendo simulada para ter certeza que tudo está ok.

Há quem questione o quanto isto é tão útil assim. Há quem demonstre que há dificuldades em operar desta forma.

Obviamente que em equipes pequenas a utilidade passa ser bem menor, mas ainda é possível se beneficiar da automação do processo completo de verificação de qualidade.

O Travis CI cuida de tudo isto (se devidamente configurado para cada tarefa, ele não adivinha nada, dá um trabalhão o tempo todo deixar tudo em ordem, mas pode poupar bastante trabalho também) e ele se comunica com diversas outras ferramentas que auxiliam o desenvolvimento de software em equipe. Ele sozinho não faz nada.

Ele controla o fluxo do repositório dos fontes, o *build* da solução, os testes diversos, de unidade, integração, de carga, performance, estáticos e dinâmicos, cria documentação, simula ou até prepara o *deploy*, eventualmente até abre *tickets* de *bug*.

[Um concorrente fala sobre CI em português](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/devops/continuous-integration/).

[Artigo da IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/rational/library/continuous-integration-agile-development/).

[Sobre o Travis CI em português](https://tableless.com.br/integracao-continua-com-travis-ci-parte-01/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Achei muito úteis a forma de explicar e o alerta de que integração contínua pode não ser benéfica. +1

Comment: Quando é falado que é todo um conjunto de testes e não só unitários, acredito que faça sentido incluir em particular os testes de integração.