# Como cria ícones "build", "download" na descrição de um projeto no github?

Tags: github, markdown

Queria saber como posso criar esses "ícones" no github...

Sou meio noob e não consigo achar o nome correto para isso, então não achei nada no Google...

Queria saber principalmente como faz os que estão depois do "Donate" que seria os: "60% of the time", "work every time", "built with"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Algumas das imagens encontradas na maioria dos projetos presentes no GitHub há a utilização da ferramenta [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org). Segue o link do que é e de como você pode usar o Travis para a criação de ícones `build passing`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/197697/122392

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eles ficam no arquivo README. Se você clicar em **Raw** ou **editar** o Readme.md de qualquer projeto, você consegue ver o código e como foi aplicado um ícone.

Sobre sua questão em relação aos emblemas/ícones que estão depois do "Donate". Eles são imagens. Você pode subir a imagem para o seu projeto ou apontar um link, caso hospedado em outro lugar. Depois é só usar [markdown](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) para aplicar o seu ícone no arquivo **README.md**.

Use markdown:

```
[![texto alternativo](http://i.imgur.com/tXSoThF.png)](http://www.twitter.com/meunome "texto título")
```

Pode ser criado também da seguinte forma:

```
[![texto alternativo][1.1]][1]

[1]: http://www.twitter.com/meunome
[1.1]: http://i.imgur.com/tXSoThF.png (texto título)
```

Você também pode contar com uma lista completa de markup emoji de markdown do github. E utilizar `:smile:`, `:laughing:` - [Lista completa aqui](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908#file-gistfile1-md)

Comment: Opa! Funcionou certinho! Muito obrigado!
Ah, achei o nome, é badges (emblemas) ou ícones mesmo.